# Solving a non-linear integrable o.d.e

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-analysis

We have given:
$$m\frac{d^2x}{dt^2} + V'(x(t))= 0\tag1$$

And:
$$E = \frac{m}{2}\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2 + V(x(t))\tag2$$
where $V(x(t))$ is a known derivable potential.

So first we have to prove that E is independent of time so $\dfrac{dE}{dt} = 0$.
It is trivial: $$\dfrac{dE}{dt} = \frac{dx}{dt}[m(\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}) + V'(x(t))]=0$$

And also i get:
$$x(t)=\sqrt{\frac{2}{m}} \int\sqrt{E-V(x(t))}dt$$
and I'm stuck here because $V$ is a function of $x$ and not of $t$. I tried finding an expression from eq$(1)$ for $\frac{dx}{dt}$ and replacing it in the eq$(2)$ but it only gets more complicated and I end up back where I started. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately life is not that easy. All you can do with equation
(2) is the following:
$$
\dot{x}^2 = \frac{E-V}{m/2} \implies
\pm\int\sqrt{\frac{m/2}{E-V}}dx = \Delta{t}
$$
And all you can do with the integral is: 
a) hope it's analytically solvable and 
b) hope the anti-derivative is invertible.
If both check out(which sometimes they do, for example in simple spring induced motion), you can have the motion of the particle.

Here's some suggested reading : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral
, it comes up in the solutions to the simple pendulum which has the exact sort of setup your question has.

Comment: thanks for your answer. If an initial condition like $x(t_0)=x_0$ is given will that make any difference? I mean can we express the integral in some other form? I think it won't make much difference but I'm not sure.

Comment: an initial condition would enable numeric methods, but the integral wouldn't be useful for that anyways.